# Collection View[Error] Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, viewcontroller

I am creating collection-view with screen transition and then An error which is "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value". I have attached picture of the error. [Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFcSf.png)

I have no idea how I fix the error. Here is My programming below.

```
class MyCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet var Mylabel :UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var Myimage :UIImageView!
    
    
    
    func setup(with hero: Hero) {
        Myimage.image = hero.image
        Mylabel.text = hero.name
        
    }
}
```

```
import UIKit

struct Hero {
    let name: String
    let image: UIImage
}

let heros: [Hero] = [
    Hero(name: "1", image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "1.png")),
    Hero(name: "2", image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "2.png")),
    Hero(name: "3", image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "3.png")),
    Hero(name: "4", image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "4.png")),
    Hero(name: "5", image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "5.png"))
]
```

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
   // var herosList = [Heros]()
    @IBOutlet weak var MyCollectionView: UICollectionView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        
        MyCollectionView.dataSource = self
        MyCollectionView.delegate = self
        MyCollectionView.collectionViewLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        
        
    }

}
    
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource{
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return heros.count
    }
    
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "MyCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell
        cell.setup(with: heros[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }
}
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: 82, height: 120)
    }
}
extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil) 
        guard let detailViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailViewController") as? DetailViewController else {
            fatalError("Failed to instantiate DetailViewController from storyboard.")
        }
        
        detailViewController.sproduct = heros[indexPath.row]
        navigationController?.pushViewController(detailViewController, animated: true)
    }
```

I googled about it. But I have no idea

Comment: can you try to put screenshot code on viewwillappear ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is may be because you don't have the value and you are force unwrapping it, Please try not to force unwrap until you are sure about that.